# JS SDK, Thrift error code 12 when getting SharedNotebooksList

Tags: javascript, evernote

It's the first time that I work with evernote,
Like the example given in the [JS SDK](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js), I create my client with the token that I get from the OAuth and I get all the notebooks of my current user so it was good for me.

But I'm facing a problem that I can't understand, when I use any method of my shared store it throw an Thrift exception with error code 12 and giving the shard id in the message.

I know that 12 error code is that the shard is temporary unavailable..
But I know that it's another thing because it's not temporary...

I have a full access api key, it work with the note store, did I miss something ?

```
// This is the example in the JS SDK    
var linkedNotebook = noteStore.listLinkedNotebooks()
.then(function(linkedNotebooks) {
   // just pick the first LinkedNotebook for this example
   return client.getSharedNoteStore(linkedNotebooks[0]);
   }).then(function(sharedNoteStore) {
   // /!\ There is the problem, throw Thrift exception !
      return sharedNoteStore.listNotebooks().then(function(notebooks) {
         return sharedNoteStore.listTagsByNotebook(notebooks[0].guid);
      }).then(function(tags) {
   // tags here is a list of Tag objects
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be an error with the SDK. I created a PR (https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js/pull/90).

You can work around this by using authenticateToSharedNotebook yourself.

```javascript
const client = new Evernote.Client({ token, sandbox });
const noteStore = client.getNoteStore();
const notebooks = await noteStore
  .listLinkedNotebooks()
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
const notebook = notebooks.find(x => x.guid === guid);
const { authenticationToken } = await client
  .getNoteStore(notebook.noteStoreUrl)
  .authenticateToSharedNotebook(notebook.sharedNotebookGlobalId);
const client2 = new Evernote.Client({
  token: authenticationToken,
  sandbox
});
const noteStore2 = client2.getNoteStore();
const [notebook2] = await noteStore2.listNotebooks();
noteStore2.listTagsByNotebook(notebook2.guid)
```